# How to change the text color inside an disabled input?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to apply a different color to the text inside the input when disabled but is not working. I'm using Material Ui

```
import React from "react";
    import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
    import Input from "@material-ui/core/Input";

    const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
      inputText: {
        color: "blue"
      }
    }));

    export default function Inputs() {
      const classes = useStyles();

      return (
        <form className={classes.root} noValidate autoComplete="off">
          <Input
            className={classes.inputText}
            defaultValue="Disabled"
            disabled
            inputProps={{ "aria-label": "description" }}
          />
        </form>
      );
    }
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-lq3e9

Comment: Can you just add `input:disabled { color: red; }` to your style sheet, substituting your desired colour in place of the ‘red’.

Comment: Does not work, you can do that in this link ? https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-lq3e9

Answer (score 1):

```js
var disabledElements = document.querySelectorAll('input[disabled]');

for (var i = 0, n = disabledElements.length; i < n; ++i) {
  disabledElements[i].style.color = 'red';
}
```

```html
<input disabled value="green" />
<input value="red" />
<input disabled />
```

Comment: You're using an normal input, I need to know how to do apply this style for a Material UI component

Comment: If you can help me out with how this renders in the UI, maybe I can help you more on this.

Comment: As I can see, in the end, that is compiled to the example that I have used for HTML. So, ideally, it should work. Just you need to see when to call the method.

Comment: Can you edit  in the link I sent you and post here ?

Answer (score 0):

I could not find your stylesheet at your sandbox link so I added a style tag and it worked.

```
<style>
    input:disabled{
      color:blue;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: This dont't work, the style is inside demo.js, I'm trying to this in a jss file